# Select with a lot of tables

Tags: mysql, select, count, sum, left-join

I'm trying to make a query for the sales report in which will be displayed the sales' code, the date, the amount of produts (only), the amount of tickets, the total sale value as well as the employee's name.
[Click here to see the connection between the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naS1L.png)
Query I'm using which doesnt return an error but only return a row even if there is nothing on the Sales table or even if it's full of them

```
select sales.codv
, customers.name as customers
, concat(day(datav),'/',month(datav),'/',year(datav)) as date
, sum(prod_sal.amount) as 'products'
, count(tickets.codb) as 'tickets'
, sum(ifnull(products.preco,0) * ifnull(prod_sal.amount,0) + 
ifnull(tickets.price,0)) as 'total/€'
, employees.nome as employee
from sales
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.codc=sales.codc
INNER JOIN employees ON employees.codf=sales.codf
LEFT JOIN prod_sal ON prod_sal.codv=sales.codv
LEFT JOIN products ON products.codp=prod_sal.codp
LEFT JOIN tickets ON tickets.codv=sales.codv
```

**NOTE**: datav is the Sales' date

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That wasn't a hint that was the answer because it worked.

Comment: Answer so that I give you the correct answer. It will be your 36,783rd correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use a `group by` clause MySQL will assume that you want to aggregate all rows that match your `where` clause. Since you don't have a `where` clause, that's everything in your db.

```
select 
  sales.codv
  , customers.name as customers
  , concat(day(datav),'/',month(datav),'/',year(datav)) as date
  , sum(prod_sal.amount) as 'products'
  , count(tickets.codb) as 'tickets'
  , sum(ifnull(products.preco,0) * ifnull(prod_sal.amount,0) + ifnull(tickets.price,0)) as 'total/€'
  , employees.nome as employee
from 
  sales
  LEFT JOIN customers 
    ON customers.codc=sales.codc
  INNER JOIN employees 
    ON employees.codf=sales.codf
  LEFT JOIN prod_sal 
    ON prod_sal.codv=sales.codv
  LEFT JOIN products 
    ON products.codp=prod_sal.codp
  LEFT JOIN tickets 
    ON tickets.codv=sales.codv
group by
  sales.codv
  , customers.name
  ,  concat(day(datav),'/',month(datav),'/',year(datav)) as date
```